# AndroidでSDカード内のデータにアクセスするには工夫が必要なのですか？

Tags: android, java

つい先日、Androidの勉強を始めたばかりで、セオリー的なものが
まだ全然解っていないので、注意点などを踏まえてご指導いただきたいのですが、

サイトなどを参考にし、『ボタンを押すとリソース中のmp3を再生する』ところまでは
できました。

それから、今度はSDカード内のデータにアクセスしようとサイトを探していると、
『機種依存なので工夫が必要』というページが多く、実際の所、どのようにして
取得すればよいのかが今一つ解りません。

http://nobuo-create.net/sdcard-2/
http://techbooster.org/android/application/16004/

上記のサイト様を参考にはさせていただいたのですが、更新年が2012,2013と古く、
現在でも同じような状況なのかどうかも解りません。

私はAndroidStudio2.2.1、多分最新の環境だと思いますが、今のバージョンでも
エミュレーターにSDを認識させるのも『/system/etc/vold.fstab』を直接
編集しないといけないのでしょうか。

また、実際に認識できた後ですが、サイト様のサンプルソース、
『// SDカードのマウント先をゲットするメソッド』にあるような手順を
踏まなければならないのは、今も同じでしょうか。

まとめますと、下記の点になります。
1.AndroidStudio2.2.1で、エミュレーターにSDカードを認識させる最新の方法
2.SDカード内のMP3ファイルを取得する方法

これらの方法を教えていただきたいのですが、ここまで動くサンプルを直接いただければ
尚　幸いです。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1):

以下の記事が参考になるかと思います。
http://umezo.hatenablog.jp/entry/20100608/1276014215

やりたいこととしては、SDカードにアクセスすることが主眼ではなく、SDカード内部に存在するMP3ファイル(もっというと音声ファイル)が取得できればよいと解釈しました。
Androidでは、Media情報を取得するためにContentResolverというクラスが存在します。
SDカード内のデータも基本的にはこのContentResolverから取得できるはずなので、試してみてはいかがでしょうか。